# How to show values in Col3 where Col1 values are true and for false values in Col1 show NULL in Col3 only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM Table
```

Results Set: ( Sample table )

```
 Col1        Col2        col3
----------- ---------- -----------
Value       Value      Value
Value       Value      Value         
Value       Value      Value         
Value       Value      Value         
Value       Value      Value
```

**Show Col3 with NULL/empty values** ( assume that Col3 supports NULL if needed ) **EXCEPT for the rows(=values) where col1 condition is true** keep the values on Col2 for all rows.

Condition as in (  `WHERE Col > 2| WHERE chareindex( 'x' , Col1 )` Etc.. )

**Table end results:** ( The conditions in here are true for rows 2 and 5 )

```
  Col1        Col2        col3
----------- ---------- -----------
1 Value       Value      NULL
2 Value       Value      Value         
3 Value       Value      NULL         
4 Value       Value      NULL         
5 Value       Value      Value
```

More expressed way for the question :

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Firstname, Lastname,
From Employees
```

Results set:

```
EmployeeID  FirstName  LastName
----------- ---------- --------------------
1           Nancy      Davolio
2           Andrew     Fuller
3           Janet      Leverling
4           Margaret   Peacock
5           Steven     Buchanan
6           Michael    Suyama
7           Robert     King
```

lets say that in the code above there's a condition for employeeID and  employeeID 3 and 6 was true to that condition

**I'm looking to achieve:**

```
EmployeeID  FirstName  LastName
----------- ---------- --------------------
1           Nancy      NULL
2           Andrew     NULL
3           Janet      Leverling
4           Margaret   NULL
5           Steven     NULL
6           Michael    Suyama
7           Robert     NULL
```

**what condition/s and how should they be put to achieve this results set**

- You may change the "base code" completely
- You don't know the values on 'Lastname' col ( or col3 )
- You must keep all the rows and columns value for the false conditions values
- The table is big

Another way of putting the question: ( based on the first paragraph of the question)

For a row which the value in col1 is true to a condition/s, show the value in Col3, if not show NULL/empty and keep the col2 values for all rows.

Comment: Proper sample data and expected output as `CREATE TABLE` `INSERT` would help immensely

Comment: Thanks for the understating to take action and point out the lacks in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to have understood exactly what you want to do, but does `SELECT` `CASE WHEN` could solve your problem ?

Here's an example :

```
SELECT
    Col1, 
    Col2,
    CASE WHEN (Condition) THEN NULL ELSE Col3 END AS Col3
FROM Table
```

It would return this output:

```
 Col1        Col2        col3
----------- ---------- -----------
5           Value      Value
21          Value      NULL         
7           Value      Value         
8           Value      Value         
40          Value      NULL
```

Using this way, you conditionally select data from the column or NULL

**EDIT** : concerning the explanation of the `case...when`, you can find explanations & examples here :
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: Edited : Although I don't understand the code the results are different from what I've requested, you need to keep Col2 values as shown in the "Table end results" .

Comment: So just select col1, col2, [case when] as col3

Comment: Just rewrite your answer and the table and that's marked as solution , also use (condition) and not >20 as a general condition , thank you for taking the time reading the question.

Comment: this is done, thank for your feedback, i appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select col1, col2, 
Case When col1 (condition) Then col3 Else null End As col3 
From Table
```

Comment: Just edit ```col1 (condition) then col3``` that's perfect .

Comment: *That's indeed the answer but I lack to understand @Acuao answer as I'm not familiar with the "case when statement"